# How can I search an array using an array list in php?

Tags: php, arrays

Good day, guys!

Please, am working on a payment system that should be able to check and display the months of the year a member didn't make payment.

To achieve this, I will fetch the months of the year s/he made payment and run it through an array of months from January - December.

i.e.

```
$array_of_months = array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');

$months[] = '';
$this_year = date('Y');
$stmt = $this->db->get_where('payment',['year'=>$this_year,'member_id'=>2]);
$result = $stmt->result();
foreach($result as $key => $val):
   $months[] = $val->month;
endforeach;
```

To get the months that didn't match the months of the year paid for, I am using array_search() and the code is as shown below:

```
if($key = array_search($months, $array_of_months) !== false):
   unset($arrays_of_months[$key]);
else:
   echo 'Nil';
endif;
```

Instead of getting the result of the IF block, what am getting the result of the ELSE block.

This is the full code:

```
$arrays_of_months = array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
$months = array();
$this_year = date('Y');
                                                    
$stmt = $this->db->get_where('payment',['year'=>$this_year]);
$result = $stmt->result();
foreach($result as $key => $val):
   $months[] = $val->month;
endforeach;

if($key = array_search($months, $arrays_of_months) !== false):
    unset($arrays_of_months[$key]);
else:
    echo 'Nil';
endif;
```

Please, what am I not doing right?

Thank you..

Comment: array_search takes needle first, and haystack second - you passed them in the opposite order.

Comment: `$months = implode(",",$months); $months = explode(",", $months);` - what is this supposed to be good for? Doing one thing, and then doing the exact opposite with the result of the first one - does _effectively_ nothing.

Comment: couldn't you use [`array_diff()`](https://3v4l.org/tDoNA)

Comment: @CBroe even with the current arrangement, the result is still the same ELSE block.

Comment: Trying to use array_search with _two_ arrays as parameter, that also makes little sense. Your best bet here, if you want to do this after the loop, is indeed `array_diff`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, array_diff() did the trick.